# Conceptual Piping TOP CPU and RAM into Jquery Graph

Tags: php, jquery, linux

So this is more of a conceptual question then an actual question. I have been thinking about piping TOP into a text file, reading that file into PHP and loading the current CPU and RAM usage statistics into a JSON value and passing that to a jquery continues moving graph. My issue currently stands, if top refreshes every 5 seconds...How do i continuously feed the JS my CPU and RAM numbers?

**EDIT**

**Cronjob Option:**

I would need to run thr cron probably every 5 seconds, would this cause an issue with the server?

**Jquery AJAX Request:**

If I had 100 visitors on at the same time it would be asking a lot more then every 5 seconds.

Comment: run a cron script every so often to put the info into a file and have jquery grab the file

Comment: both your options are bad ideas get some real logging software like **nagios**

Comment: @PatrickEvans If the cron is run every 5 seconds or so, would that cause issues running it that often?

Comment: @HydraIO not if the script is small which it only needs 1 line of code to get that info, or better yet do what dagon says and use an actual logging software.

Comment: I don't really want an entire software suite, I just wanted a single continuous graph of RAM and CPU

Comment: hint, hint: `usage:  top -hv | -bcisSHM -d delay -n iterations`.. `top -d5 -n10000 | yourPhpProcess`... Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to write a small program that would write a file in memory that would contain the filtered information from `/proc/cpuinfo` and `/proc/meminfo`. This program should execute periodically, maybe blocked with a select with timeout. Then a CGI should request just the info from that file.